# Findout all the memory address a process has occupied by its process Id

Tags: c++, wdk, kmdf

I  have a program written in c# and it consists of two variable x and y which have a fixed value. The PID of this program is, for ex: 34432. From kernel driver, I want to find the memory addresses of this process and replace the fixed value of x and y in that program with different value. How do I make it possible using the PID of the program?

I'm looking to the reference of this git repo, I don't want to rather manually type an address of a variable of a process like he did.
https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/KernelReadWriteMemory/blob/master/ReadWrite.c

Comment: If you were in user space, you could use [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) to determine the layout of the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of a process. However, I don't know how to accomplish this in kernel space.

Comment: You mention C# in the question, but tagged it with C++ what is it now?

Comment: @asynts: I assume that the kernel driver is programmed in C++ and that the user space program (whose memory is to be manipulated) is programmed in C#. Since the question is about the kernel driver and not the user space program, the question is tagged correctly.

Comment: @asynts it's not going to matter. I could have written the same logic in other language and it still wouldn't have matter.

Comment: I have manipulated using kmdf by hard coding the PID and memory address of two variables of a c# program. I don't want to hard code memory addresses of x and y this time. So, I want to scan all the memory the process is consuming from kernel.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use a kernel driver for this? You can read and write memory of other processes from user space using [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) and [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory). Therefore, if that is all you want, a kernel mode driver is not required.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah, I'm pretty sure. Thank you for showing your concerns atleast.